# debian: how to divert sound from snd-hda-intel to snd-usb-audio?

Tags: linux, usb, audio, debian

Under Debian stretch, Linux 4.1.0, xfce4: how to divert audio output from the on-board speaker to a USB sound bar?

Trying to make sense of various web pages, I modified `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` as follows:

```
options snd-usb-audio index=0
options snd-hda-intel index=-2,-2
```

Result of `cat /proc/asound/cards`:

```
 0 [SoundBar       ]: USB-Audio - Dell AC511 USB SoundBar
                      Dell Dell AC511 USB SoundBar at usb-0000:00:14.0-2.4.1, full speed
 1 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                      HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7c34000 irq 31
 2 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7c30000 irq 30
```

Without avail: sound still goes to the onboard speaker. Funnily though, volume can be regulated with the soundbar's knob.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I found the easiest thing is to use `pavucontrol`, (PulseAudio Volume Control), freely available from the repos.

Once you open its GUI, under `Configuration`, you will be able to choose your output medium.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Sound still comes from the on-board speaker. Volume knob of the soundbar still controls the built-in analog output. If that is muted, no sound at all.

Comment: @JoachimWuttke Did you first check, in the configuration panel, that the sound be sent the sound bar instead of the analog speaker? Does the sound bar appear at all in the **Configuration** panel?

Comment: Yes, the soundbar appears. Unmuting it and muting all other channels causes no sound to be played at all.